# Как добавить rust в UE4/UE5?

Tags: rust, unreal-engine-4, unreal-engine

говорят, что во все движки, которые созданы под с++ можно добавить поддержку раст. Анриал кажется мне удобным поэтому и возник такой вопрос. Как писать на Rust в Unreal Engine?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Думаю, нужно обратится к разработчикам ue4/ue5, но на их месте я бы просто ответил известным мемом с двумя священниками

Comment: Скорее мемом с буханкой-троллейбусом...